# Keystore file not found not found for signing config 'release' flutter

Tags: java, flutter, keystore

I followed all the steps from generating a key - updating the key.properties with the typed password,

I added link where the key that was created.
[image]

I keep having a failure - keystore file not found for signing config release

[image]

The gradle file is properly updated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the "" of your path to "/"
thats worked for me